# Send KafkaStreams jmx metrics with java datadog agent

Tags: monitoring, apache-kafka-streams, jmx, datadog

I'm using the [dd javaagent](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup_overview/setup/java/?tab=containers) method to launch my java application that is a Kafka streams application.  I'd like the kafkastreams metrics defined [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/monitoring.html#accessing-metrics-via-jmx-and-reporters) to be shipped to dd, however dd is not getting them.

the `dd.jmxfetch.enabled` arg is set to true, which it already is by default anyway. I'm unsure if I need to create any other `metrics.yaml` file or `jmx.yaml` datadog config for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

From the Datadog documentation [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/runtime_metrics/java/) , when you are using the java tracer `-javaagent:_datadog/javaagent.jar` within your application, you can specify the Kafka Integration:
DD_JMXFETCH_KAFKA_ENABLED: "true"

This will use a pre-defined list of jmx metrics for Kafka.
Then in Datadog, you should see some metrics starting with `kafka.stream`

Comment: where do you set the DD_JMXFETCH_KAFKA_ENABLED flag to true?